# Cannot move URL to import URL in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

django 2.2.5

I haven't been having problems moving urls until now.

reporting/reporting.html (index):

```
...
{% url "line_chart_json" %}
...
```

reporting/views.py

```
class LineChartJSONView(BaseLineChartView):
    def get_labels(self):
        """Return 7 labels for the x-axis."""
        return ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"]
    ....
```

When it's in the main app url.py, it's fine

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from reporting.views import LineChartJSONView
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('reporting/', include('reporting.urls')),
    path('line_chart/json/', LineChartJSONView.as_view(),
          name='line_chart_json'),
]
```

When I move it to reporting

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import LineChartJSONView

app_name = 'reporting'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.summary_properties_user,
         name='index'),
    path('line_chart/json/', LineChartJSONView.as_view(),
         name='line_chart_json'),
]
```

I get an error coming back from it's use on reporting.html:

```
NoReverseMatch at /reporting/
Reverse for 'line_chart_json' not found. 'line_chart_json' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I assume a simple oversight.  Only a few weeks in, and Django URLs are still something to get my head around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the reporting app now, so you need the prefix:

```
{% url "reporting:line_chart_json" %}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Turns out I did try that, but it's possible I had something cached, or hadn't reset my other changes properly.  I think I was eating my own tail at some point re-bugging it.  Thanks.